# jQuery doesn't recognize html string

Tags: jquery, html

I am using an MVC framework and I am making ajax request to an action and the response data is an html page, which is something like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class='no-js' lang='en' ng-app="gd">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

But the problem comes when I try to select something from that html- an "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: and here is the whole html" error occur. I searched the web for some solution and what I found was that jQuery 1.9 recognize html strings only if they start with html tag and if there are any whitespaces the above error occur. I try to use the $.parseHtml() function, but still there is no change. Does anybody have any solution for that problem?

Ok, here is my script:

```
success : function(data) {
                        $(data).find(".goalSection").each(function() {
                            $("goalsSection:last").append($(this));
                        });
                        start = start+5;
                    }
```

This is what happens on ajax request success.

Comment: Can you show your code and the actual HTML you get back (or at least the first line)

Comment: The first lines are exactly the code I gave in my question

Comment: Can you show us the script that tries to "use" that html?

Comment: what do you mean by "I try to select something from that html-"

Comment: I guess it's because of the comments outside of the html element. Also, when using ie<9 you'll have 2 <html> starttags!

Comment: The jQuery code might be helpful too ;)

Comment: I added the script in my question. @Willem I also suppose that this is what cause the error, but how to solve it without modifying my html?

Comment: Load the document into a string variable, cut everything before the starting `<html>` tag off with string manipulation methods, and then use parseHTML on that …?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery unrecognized expression on Ajax response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667441/jquery-unrecognized-expression-on-ajax-response)