# JSF + jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf

I'm having troubles when using jQuery Ajax for loading content - I get an error when trying to load a page using the statement below:

```
$.ajax({
  url : "/shop/ajax/category/" + id,
  success : onCategoryLoaded,
  dataType : "html"
});
```

If the page I'm is plain html then everything is fine - however if I include a `ui:composition` tag so I can use `ui:repeat` and so on, then it fails due to 'unrecognized expression'.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have included all the required taglib at the beginning of the jsf

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
```

And this may be helpful:

> If you are using jQuery1.9, the problem may lie in the content being
>   loaded. There is a new update which requires that the first character
>   in the response be a < [AKA the less than symbol]. Even whitespace
>   will cause this to break and throw the dreaded "Uncaught Error: Syntax
>   error, unrecognized expression:" error.
>
> I'd recommend checking this before using the suggested workaround
>   above. Its not a bug its a security effort.
>
> http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-htmlstring-versus-jquery-selectorstring

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16305980/1420186

Comment: You we're right. I had a space between the ui:composition tag and the first < once that gap was removed it worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user2848952 Check this answer as accepted so everybody knows that your question has been answered.